# System.Array.IndexOf allocates memory

Tags: c#, .net-core, profiling, system.array

I've been profiling my code and found that `System.Array.IndexOf` is allocating a fair bit of memory. I've been trying to find out how come this happens.

[image: profiler image]

```
public struct LRItem
{
    public ProductionRule Rule { get; } // ProductionRule is a class
    public int Position { get; }
}

// ...

public List<LRItem> Items { get; } = new List<LRItem>();

// ...

public bool Add(LRItem item)
{
    if (Items.Contains(item)) return false;

    Items.Add(item);
    return true;
}
```

I'm assuming the `IndexOf` is called by `Items.Contains` because I don't think `Items.Add` has any business checking indices. I've tried looking at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/array.cs.html#https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/array.cs.html) and [.NET Core source](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Array.cs) but to no avail. Is this a bug in the VS profiler? Is this function actually allocating memory? Could I optimize my code somehow?

Comment: Are you perhaps setting the capacity of your list to some high value before you see the memory allocations in IndexOf happen?

Comment: Check how `LRItem` actually implements `Equals`. The culprit might very well be there.

Comment: Also, if you need a collection that enforces uniqueness, then use a type that already provides that functionality.

Comment: @elgonzo no, I'm not setting or changing capacity anywhere

Comment: @InBetween I've no custom Equals for LRItem

Comment: Contains() has no reason to allocate any memory, but the Add() on the next line does. So make sure you do a Clean and a Rebuild. Wouldn't hurt to manually delete some pdb and dll files first.  If this persists it might be very educational to construct a [mcve]. Id does look a litle like a problem in the profiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is probably a bit late, but in case anyone else has the same question...

When `List<T>.Contains(...)` is called, it uses the `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to compare the individual items to find what you've passed in[1]. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1.default?view=netcore-3.1) say this about `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`:

> The Default property checks whether type T implements the System.IEquatable interface and, if so, returns an EqualityComparer that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it returns an EqualityComparer that uses the overrides of Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by T.

Since your `LRItem` does *not* implement `IEquatable<T>`, then it falls back to using `Object.Equals(object, object)`. And because `LRItem` is a struct, then it will end up **being boxed** as an `object` so it can be passed in to `Object.Equals(...)`, which is where the allocations are coming from.

The easy fix for this is to take a hint from the docs and implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface:

```cs
public struct LRItem : IEquatable<LRItem>
{
    // ...

    public bool Equals(LRItem other)
    {
        // Implement this
        return true;
    }
}
```

This will now cause `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to return a specialised comparer that does not need to box your `LRItem` structs and hence avoiding the allocation.

[1] I'm not sure if something's changed since this question was asked (or maybe it's a .net framework vs core difference or something) but [`List<T>.Contains()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,521b9f7129105e15) doesn't call `Array.IndexOf()` nowadays. Either way, both of them *do* defer to `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`, which means that this should still be relevant in either case.